# How does Python distinguish callback function which is a member of a class?

Tags: python

Please look at the simple example:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self, flag):
    self.flag = flag

  def func(self):
    print self.flag

a = A(1)
b = A(2)
callback_a = a.func
callback_b = b.func

callback_a()
callback_b()
```

The result is:

```
1
2
```

It runs as expected. But I have a question. In C, the callback function is passed as a pointer. In Python, it should have a similar way to do this, so the caller knows the address of the function. But in my example, not only the function pointer is passed, but also the parameter (self) is passed, because the same method of the same class prints different results. So my questions are:

1. Does such a method in Python only has one copy in memory? My meaning is that the code of any method only has one copy, and in my example the method won't be cloned itself. I think it should have only one copy, but here I still make this question in order to get more inputs.
2. I remember everything in Python is an object. So in my example, are there two function instances with different parameters but only one copy of code?

Comment: I would think it creates a closure?

Comment: You should be using newstyle classes. Subclass everything from `object` or something that subclasses it.

Comment: @aaronasterling: Though I am not sure it has too much impact on the question at hand?

Comment: @jdi There's always an opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: @aaronasterling it doesn't even make sense to recommend it in this scenario, as there is no specific version of python specified.  Old style classes are gone in python 3.x, and new styles are the default.

Comment: @Darthfett. Observe the `print` _statements_.

Comment: @flypen, Greg's response is probably the better one and has a lot of useful information in the comments so it should probably be the accepted answer....

Comment: @aaronasterling ah, my bad.  Must've missed that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Specific to CPython, there is only one copy of the function object. During instance creation, the class wraps the unbound functions in its namespace as bound methods. But they all wrap the same function.

Here's your example expanded to show what's going on.

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, flag):
    self.flag = flag

  def func(self):
    print self.flag

a = A(1)
b = A(2)

callback_a = a.func
callback_b = b.func

print "typeof(callback_a) = {0}".format(type(callback_a))
print "typeof(callback_b) = {0}".format(type(callback_b))

print "typeof(callback_a.__func__) = {0}".format(type(callback_a.__func__))
print "typeof(callback_b.__func__) = {0}".format(type(callback_b.__func__))

print "'callback_a.__func__ is callback_b.__func__'  is {0}".format(callback_a.__func__ is callback_b.__func__)

callback_a()
callback_b()
```

This code outputs

```
typeof(callback_a) = <type 'instancemethod'>
typeof(callback_b) = <type 'instancemethod'>
typeof(callback_a.__func__) = <type 'function'>
typeof(callback_b.__func__) = <type 'function'>
'callback_a.__func__ is callback_b.__func__'  is True
```

You can clearly see, using the `is` operator, that both `instancemethod` classes are sharing the same function object.

Comment: I'd like to know why this got downvoted. If there's something objectively wrong, then I'd like to know.

Comment: What I find really interesting is that this  `print "'callback_a is callback_b'  is {0}".format(callback_a is callback_b)` prints *false*.
Coming from Javascript and Perl I find this behavior really surprising.  Are there Python documents that say more about it?

Comment: `callback_a is callback_b` is `False` because each is an `instancemethod` that wraps both the function **AND** the instance with which to call that method. Both share the same `__func__` (as shown in the initial post), but each has a different `self` object instance with which that function is called. Make sense?

Answer (score 24):

In Python, the callback is not simply a reference to a member function. Instead, it is "bound" to the object that it refers to when it was created. So `a.func` creates a callable that is bound to `a`, and `b.func` creates a callable that is bound to `b`.

Python only needs one implementation of `func()` in memory, but it will probably create one or more "trampoline" functions at runtime to accomplish the binding (I'm not certain of the internal details on this, and it would differ between Python implementations anyway).

If you print `id(callback_a)` and `id(callback_b)` you will get different results, showing that they are indeed different callable objects.

Comment: And if you do `id(b.func) == id(a.func)` you find that they point to the same memory

Comment: @jdi: Can you tell me why `id(a.func)` gives different result each time?

Comment: @mshsayem `id` is implemented as the memory address of the object in CPython. So it's getting a different location in memory each time the program runs.

Comment: @mshsayem Because we have to store the self pointer somewhere (at least conceptually but also in reality - for cpython). Basically it's a struct `Py_Object *self, *func` and we obviously can't share the struct because self is always different. If you want the actual function object you can do `Class.func` (which you can also call, eg try `A.func(a)` in your code) - the function object should be the same (at least in cpython!)

Comment: @jdi: that's purely an implementation detail and isn't guaranteed, though.  For example, I just tried it on pypy and ironpython and they weren't equal.

Comment: @jdi Try `a_func = a.func; b_func = b.func; id(a_func) == id(b_func)`.  `a.func` and `b.func` are different bound method objects.  In CPython bound method objects are constructed on attribute access and not cached.  When you do `id(a.func)` a new bound method is constructed, you get its id, then it is immediately garbage collected since there are no more references to it.  When you then do `id(b.func)` the new bound method is constructed in the same piece of memory, so your equality is true by coincidence.