# Workaround for equality of nested functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, pyglet

I have a nested function that I'm using as a callback in `pyglet`:

```
def get_stop_function(stop_key):
    def stop_on_key(symbol, _):
        if symbol == getattr(pyglet.window.key, stop_key):
            pyglet.app.exit()
    return stop_on_key

pyglet.window.set_handler('on_key_press', get_stop_function('ENTER'))
```

But then I run into problems later when I need to reference the nested function again:

```
pyglet.window.remove_handler('on_key_press', get_stop_function('ENTER'))
```

This doesn't work because of the way python treats functions:

```
my_stop_function = get_stop_function('ENTER')
my_stop_function is get_stop_function('ENTER')  # False
my_stop_function == get_stop_function('ENTER')  # False
```

Thanks to two [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216597/how-should-functions-be-tested-for-equality-or-identity) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977808/why-dont-methods-have-reference-equality) I understand what is going on but I'm not sure  what the workaround is for my case. I'm looking through the [pyglet source code](https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet/event.py) and it looks like pyglet uses equality to find the handler to remove.

So my final question is: how can I override the inner function's `__eq__` method (or some other dunder) so that identical nested functions will be equal?

(Another workaround would be to store a reference to the function myself, but that is duplicating pyglet's job, will get messy with many callbacks, and anyways I'm curious about this question!)

Edit: actually, in the questions I linked above, it's explained that methods have value equality but not reference equality. With nested functions, you don't even get value equality, which is all I need.

Edit2: I will probably accept Bi Rico's answer, but does anyone know why the following doesn't work:

```
def get_stop_function(stop_key):
    def stop_on_key(symbol, _):
        if symbol == getattr(pyglet.window.key, stop_key):
            pyglet.app.exit()
    stop_on_key.__name__ = '__stop_on_' + stop_key + '__'
    stop_on_key.__eq__ = lambda x: x.__name__ == '__stop_on_' + stop_key + '__'
    return stop_on_key

get_stop_function('ENTER') == get_stop_function('ENTER')  # False
get_stop_function('ENTER').__eq__(get_stop_function('ENTER'))  # True
```

Comment: Does "the same function" mean identical code (as in, both created by `get_stop_function`), equal code, or different code with equal bytecode string? Identical or equal closure? And so on…

Comment: You actually _can_ override the inner function's `__eq__`. In Python 3.x, `function` is mutable. The problem is that it won't do any good. Python 3.x specifies that `__eq__` lookup is allowed to ignore the instance's methods and go straight to the class, and at least CPython 3.0-3.4 and PyPy3 2.1 (which are the only 3.x implementations that exist) do exactly that.

Comment: Also, for your edit: I'm pretty sure that methods are equal iff the function is equal and the bound object is equal, which means methods have effectively the same issue as nested functions—the functions still need to compare equal. It's just that normally you don't build bound methods yourself, they get created by the class's descriptor, and in that case their functions will always be identical. (I get the feeling I didn't explain that very well…)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a class for your stop functions and define your own comparison method.

```
class StopFunction(object):

    def __init__(self, stop_key):
        self.stop_key = stop_key

    def __call__(self, symbol, _):
        if symbol == getattr(pyglet.window.key, self.stop_key):
            pyglet.app.exit()

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return self.stop_key == other.stop_key
        except AttributeError:
            return False

StopFunciton('ENTER') == StopFunciton('ENTER')
# True
StopFunciton('ENTER') == StopFunciton('FOO')
# False
```

Comment: I am not shure if pyglet internally compares for equality, or for identity. This might not work on the later case. Transposing the nested function to a class can increase readability, though - and it can be done to work by overriding `__new__` to ensure a single object for each stop_key is created.

Comment: @jsbueno: According to the question it uses equality.

Comment: @jsbueno the question explicit asks how to override the function's comparison method, though memoizing the functions should also work here and might have other benefits.

Comment: @BiRico what other benefits?

Comment: The main benefit of memoization is usually performance when large computation are involved, but there can be little things that crop up. For example you can use functions as keys into a dictionary. In order to use instances of `StopFunction` as keys to a dictionary, the class would need to define a `__hash__` method. Also, as @jsbueno mentioned, the two approaches don't conflict, you could memoizes instances of the class if there was a performance issue.

Comment: You can do this more generally by, e.g., wrapping and delegating to a function, making `__eq__` compare `__code__` and `__closure__` and whatever else is relevant, etc. If you're doing this for 20 different functions, that's probably worth doing.

Answer (score 3):

the solution is to keep a dictionary containing the generated functions around,
so that when you make the second call, you get the same object as in the first call.

That is, simply build some memoization logic, or use one of the libraries
existing with memoizing decorators:

```
ALL_FUNCTIONS = {}
def get_stop_function(stop_key):
    if not stop_key in ALL_FUNCTIONS:
        def stop_on_key(symbol, _):
            if symbol == getattr(pyglet.window.key, stop_key):
                pyglet.app.exit()
        ALL_FUNCTIONS[stop_key] = stop_on_key
     else:
        stop_on_key = ALL_FUNCTIONS[stop_key]
    return stop_on_key
```

Comment: I did state in the question that I didn't want to have to save a reference to the function, though this is more elegant than I was imagining... I do like this solution but I think I still prefer @BiRico's.

Answer (score 3):

You can generalize Bi Rico's solution to allow wrapping any functions up with some particular equality function pretty easily.

The first problem is defining what the equality function should check. I'm guessing for this case, you want the code to be identical (meaning functions created from the same `def` statement will be equal, but two functions created from character-for-character copies of the `def` statement will not), and the closures to be equal (meaning that if you call `get_stop_function` with two equal but non-identical `stop_key`s the functions will be equal), and nothing else to be relevant. But that's just a guess, and there are many other possibilities.

Then you just wrap a function the same way you'd wrap any other kind of object; just make sure `__call__` is one of the things you delegate:

```
class EqualFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.__code__ == other.__code__ and 
                all(x.cell_contents == y.cell_contents 
                    for x, y in zip(self.__closure__, other.__closure__)))
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.f, attr)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to support other dunder methods that aren't required to go through `getattr` (I don't think any of them are critical for functions, but I could be wrong…), either do it explicitly (as with `__call__`) or loop over them and add a generic wrapper to the type for each one.

To use the wrapper:

```
def make_f(i):
    def f():
        return i
    return EqualFunction(f)
f1 = f(0)
f2 = f(0.0)
assert f1 == f2
```

Or, notice that `EqualFunction` actually works as a decorator, which may be more readable.

So, for your code:

```
def get_stop_function(stop_key):
    @EqualFunction
    def stop_on_key(symbol, _):
        if symbol == getattr(pyglet.window.key, stop_key):
            pyglet.app.exit()
    return stop_on_key
```